# How to set table column widths to the longest value, excluding header

Tags: html, css

I have some tables with data in HTML. I am trying to figure out how to dynamically set the column width (preferably with CSS) to fit the longest value, but I would like the column headers to be word wrapped because they are quite long in comparison.

For example I have

```
Percentage of Items purchased
40%
60%
30%
```

and I would like for the column width to fit the values 40%, 60%, 30%, and have "Percentage of Items purchased" word-wrapped.

Comment: I am going to add padding to the table cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your stylesheet Add:

`white-space:nowrap;` to your `TD`, but not to your `TH`.